# how to specify headers[To] in a mail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer, mailnotifier

I am sending a email

```
mail from: from_email, to: members_email_id, subject: mail_subject, :reply_to => to_email
```

the mail is going, but i want to customize "To", instead of users email I want to show "xyz@abc.com" in "To".

Can we change it using headers['To']? , like  " headers['Delivered-To'] = to_email " .

Answer (score 0):

What is the question here? You want to send an email to someone at members_email_id but want to show "xyz@abc.com" in the to field?

to: is where the email will be delivered to so unless you want it sent to xyz@abc.com it won't work.

All headers can be set as headers[field] = value or as a hash headers({'field'=>'value','field'=>'value'})